# Trying to get an ajax call working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've got a page with three checkbox options. I want to use these three checkboxes as a filter for data. I've got the three checkboxes filtering if the user manually submits the form.

I'd like to remove the submit button, so whenever the user selects one of the options in my form, the options get sent to the ajax. At presently, my code only sends the last checkbox selected, its because I have got this.value in search. I'm not quite sure how I loop through all the checked boxes in my form and send this across. The second thing I'm having trouble with is the fetch.php is a 'secure' page that only connects to the database to retrieve data if certain username and password are setup appropriately in the session variable. If I call the fetch page with ajax, I take it treats it as accessing this page outside the scope of the client, i.e. the session variable wont of passed through the credentials even if the user is logged in from the page calling the ajax. Is that correct? To rectify this I've tried to pass through username password through the data line, have I got my data line setup correctly for multiple parameters?

```
<form id="form">
    <div class="filterblock">
          <input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="search[]" value="Cars" class="category">
        <label for="check1">Cars</label>
    </div>

    <div class="filterblock">
          <input id="check2" type="checkbox" name="search[]" value="Trucks" class="category">
        <label for="check2">Trucks</label>
    </div>

    <div class="filterblock">
          <input id="check3" type="checkbox" name="search[]" value="Bikes" class="category">
        <label for="check3">Bikes</label>
    </div>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm()" />

    </form>
```

AJAX call

```
$('.category').change(function () {

    var user = <?php echo $_SESSION['login']['logged_username'] ;?>;
    var pass = <?php echo $_SESSION['login']['logged_password'] ;?>;

$.ajax({
    url: fetch.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {search: this.value, user: user, pass: pass},
dataType:'html',
    success:function(data)
    {
        $('#result').html(data);
    }

    });
});
```

Comment: Two things.  Are you using checkboxes (multiple selection) in place of radio buttons? (single selection).  Also, this `<?php echo $_SESSION['login']['logged_username'] ;?>` will fail because you need to wrap it in quotation marks for Javascript to use it.

Comment: Yes, I'm using checkboxes for multiple selections.I deal with multiple selections in my query on my fetch.php page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might approximate your goal.  Use `jQuery.serialize()` to grab all the form data.

```
$('.category').change(function() {

    var user = "<?php echo $_SESSION['login ']['logged_username '] ;?>";
    var pass = "<?php echo $_SESSION['login ']['logged_password '] ;?>";

    var data = $('#form').serialize();
    data.user = user;
    data.pass = pass;
    data.search = this.value;
    $.ajax({
        url: fetch.php ',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you codenoir, couldn't get the user and pass to set in data, I tried literal strings, removed the php element to try but it didn't work. Found out in the end realised I didn't need them. I just need to pass through search criteria.